# Is it possible to interact with third-party software and the Dark project keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I am an aspiring programmer and would like to try my hand at something to get some practice and skills. I recently bought a keyboard from dark project, but since the keyboard is new it seems that the software is not finished yet, (model dp one skeleton 87a) I noticed that there are more backlighting modes in the full version of the PP, and the question came up, can I add third party backlighting modes for this keyboard without knowing much about the software? If it is possible, how to realise it?

Unfortunately I didn't find anything needed for my idea or at least an sdk to try to implement it.